# I have applied Materialize CSS but still not showing icons

Tags: css, asp.net

[image: See the icon names i placed in <i>tag</i>]
I have applied Materialize CSS in my ASP.NET Project but still not showing icons..
Its just showing Icon name instead of Real Icon
And I Use 2 Asp Radio Buttons and bind with Materialized CSS ..
But now non of them are select-able[image: Radio Button Code with Materialize CSS]
Can anyone help me [image: See I Placed Materialize CSS Library]
Thank you ....
Radio Button Code :

```
<div>
<asp:Label ID="lblMale" runat="server" class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="MALE">
<asp:RadioButton ID="MALE" runat="server" CssClass="mdl-radio__button" Text="MALE" GroupName="G"/><span class = "mdl-radio__label">MALE</span></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblFemale" runat="server" class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="FEMALE">
<asp:RadioButton ID="FEMALE" runat="server" CssClass="mdl-radio__button" GroupName="G" Text="FEMALE" /><span class = "mdl-radio__label">FEMALE</span></asp:Label></div>
```

Icon Code :

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon">
<i class="material-icons">face</i>
</span>
<div class="form-group label-floating">
<label class="control-label">First Name <small>(required)</small></label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst_Name" runat="server" CssClass="form-control
</asp:TextBox>
</div>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon">
<i class="material-icons">record_voice_over</i>
</span>
<div class="form-group label-floating">
<label class="control-label">Last Name <small>(required)</small></label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLast_Name" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<asp:Label ID="lblMale" runat="server" class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="MALE">
<asp:RadioButton ID="MALE" runat="server" CssClass="mdl-radio__button" Text="MALE" GroupName="G"/>
<span class = "mdl-radio__label">MALE</span>
</asp:Label>           
<asp:Label ID="lblFemale" runat="server" class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="FEMALE">
<asp:RadioButton ID="FEMALE" runat="server" CssClass="mdl-radio__button" GroupName="G" Text="FEMALE" />
<span class = "mdl-radio__label">FEMALE</span>
</asp:Label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: we have to find solution for you and you are not ready to provide your code how easy is that..

Comment: how rude you are you need answer but not ready to put effort....

Comment: Add some of your code, perhaps you should make js fiddle

Comment: ASP RadioButton Code :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're loading the Material Icons font

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<i class="material-icons">face</i>
```

Comment: From where I can download the full Icon library for local use ?

Comment: This will download a zip w/ the True Type Font:
https://fonts.google.com/download?family=Material%20Icons

...and this will download the Web Font:
https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v36/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.woff2